# How to sort an Object[] array based on one of its elements?

Tags: java

I need your assiatance please:

I have a map :

```
Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
```

The Object[] array is built out of triples: [String, String, Integer]

Later on, I am going to read the object[] array values, but I should print them sorted according to the integer value.

How can I do this in the best way?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not create a class with 2 String, and an Integer field, rather than this bizarre Object array? Are you going to sort Object[]'s according to the Integer in them? Map is not useful at all for sorting, you can get the valueSet of the map which will be a `Set<Object[]>` and from this set, you can sort according to the Integer value.

Comment: @bureaquete Well, I was just using an example I have found of using APACHE POI API. There they used a map of a row number and an array of its values, whihch may be of different types.

Comment: What do you mean by 'best'?

Comment: @Alex The most effective, most elegant. But any solution will be blessed :-)

Comment: Why do you do `new HashMap<String, Object[]>()` ? Don't you use Java 7+? With streams, it will be much easier to do the sorting. Only if it were not a Object[] but a complex object.

Comment: @bureaquete As I said - I am basing my code to the POI API, and they used this method of storing the row data. And I didn't want to spend time on changing it and taking the risk I will fail. So I'd currently like to continue with their code. This is regardless to the fact that you are right :-)

Comment: @dushkin Sorry, I just cannot stop thinking of refactoring all that code!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is with a stream:

```
data.values().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> (Integer)a[2]))
    .forEachOrdered(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
```

Comment: Not only a way, but the most elegant way, who, in this day and age, still creates custom comparators?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to extract the values from the map. Then you can use a sort method implementation from native java, with your custom comparator.

```
Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
List<Object[]> values = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
values.addAll(data.values());
Collections.sort(values, new Comparator<Object[]>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2)
    {
        // TODO implement me
        // o1 less than o2 ? return -1
        // o1 greater than o2 ? return 1
        // o1 equals o2 ? return 0
    }
});
```

In this example you only need to implement the compare method. From the docs:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer,
>   zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal
>   to, or greater than the second.

You can also take a look at: [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: Yep thats exactly what should be done. I wanted to answere the same but I had an appointment . Notice, that his Object can also implement Comparable wich would render the instantiation of a new ArrayList unnessasary

Comment: We have Java 8 so the diamond shortcut for a generic type can be used. Plus, we have streams.

Comment: the diamond shortcut is available since Java 7.

Answer (score 2):

Use Java 8 to sort the values.

```
final Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("foo", new Object[]{"A", "B", 1});
data.put("bar", new Object[]{"C", "D", 2});
data.put("baz", new Object[]{"E", "F", 3});

final Comparator<Object[]> comparator = (oa1, oa2) ->
   ((Integer) oa1[2]).compareTo((Integer) oa2[2]);

List<Object[]> sorted = 
    data.values().stream().sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
```